# SQL Server 2008 Schedule Timed Job to Run

Tags: sql-server-2008, job-scheduling

I have a .sql script file that I want to run once every 24 hours.  What are the best (and easiest) steps to produce a scheduled task in SQL Server 2008 to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: See about SQL Agent here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the SQL Server Agent (if you are not using the Express version of SQL Server).  In Management Studio, expand the SQL Server Agent node, right-click on Jobs and click New Job...

From there you will be able to schedule all kinds of jobs, including running a script every 24 hours.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do... is there a good source that details this?

Comment: Actually yes.  Here you go http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlagent/archive/2010/10/14/creating-a-regularly-scheduled-job.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can create a job with the [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx).

> SQL Server Agent uses SQL Server to store job information. Jobs
>   contain one or more job steps. Each step contains its own task, for
>   example, backing up a database.
>
> SQL Server Agent can run a job on a schedule, in response to a
>   specific event, or on demand. For example, if you want to back up all
>   the company servers every weekday after hours, you can automate this
>   task. Schedule the backup to run after 22:00 Monday through Friday; if
>   the backup encounters a problem, SQL Server Agent can record the event
>   and notify you.

You can run a job based on a specific schedule and it can execute  a stored procedure, SSIS, etc.

To create a new job, in SQL Server Management Studio, under the SQL Server Agent, right-click the Jobs and select New Job.

[image]

Here is a step by step from MSDN on creating a job:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx

Comment: This is what I want indeed, but I'm not extremely clear on what to do after this step.

Comment: @AdamLevitt I updated my answer with a step by step from MSDN on creating a job

Answer (score 0):

In you SQL Server Agent 
1. right click jobs to add a new job 
2. Give it a name and make sure the owner has the access the execute access to the database. 
3. under steps and a new step. You can simply copy paste the script in the text area, select the database you want to run in on click OK. 
4. under schedule click add new schedule and select time, occurrence, start and end time 
5. click ok and you are done. 
Hope it helps you and anyone else who came across this and still wasn't sure how it works just like me :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do not have SQL agent or full SQL version: you could schedule a task to run a batch file in Windows scheduler that "calls" on the SQL script. This is my batch file for example: **SQLCMD.EXE -S sqlServerInstanceName -E -i C:_software\mySQLscript2Execute.sql** . Remember to save your file with .bat extension. Thanks : chagbert